# Cruzando listas em python

Tags: python-3.x

Boa noite, estou quebrando a cabeça para achar o erro, é o seguinte estou cruzando está lista de números binários, o primeiro cruzamento está dando certo porém o segundo está ficando com o final do primeiro, para exemplificar está é minha minha lista de entrada:

### POPULAÇÃO SELECIONADA

```
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1']
['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
```

Estes são os que vão cruzar em pares (pai e mãe):

### CROSSOVER

```
 INDICES: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8]
 Corte em: 6
 Pai: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
 Mae: ['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1']
 Corte em: 2
 Pai: ['1', '1', '0', '0', '0', '1']
 Mae: ['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
 Corte em: 1
 Pai: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
 Mae: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
 Corte em: 2
 Pai: ['0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '1']
 Mae: ['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
```

E está é minha saida que está errada:

### POPULAÇÃO CROSSOVER

```
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '1', '1', '1']
['1', '1', '0', '0', '1', '1']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '1']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['0', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['1', '0', '1', '0', '1', '0']
```

### CÓDIGO

```
def crossover(probCrossover):
    indices = []
    randoms = []

    print('\nCROSSOVER')
    print('-----'*6)
    for i in range(len(populacao)):
        randoms.append(random())

    for i , r in enumerate(randoms):
        if r <= probCrossover:
            indices.append(i)

    if len(indices)%2!=0:
        indices.pop()
    print('\nINDICES: {}'.format(indices))
    for ind in range(0, len(indices), 2):

        pontoCorte = randint(1, precind)
        print('Corte em: {}'.format(pontoCorte))
        print('Pai: {}\nMae: {}'.format(populacao[indices[ind]], populacao[indices[ind+1]]))

        populacao.__setitem__(indices[ind], populacao[indices[ind]][0:pontoCorte]+populacao[indices[ind+1]][pontoCorte:])
        populacao.__setitem__(indices[ind+1], populacao[indices[ind+1]][0:pontoCorte]+populacao[indices[ind]][pontoCorte:])
```

Comment: O que significa "cruzar" a lista? Pode dar um exemplo da entrada e saída desejadas, e postar todo o código necessário pra tornar o problema reproduzível?

Comment: Bom a entrada é ah 'população selecionada' que mostrei logo acima. Cruzara é assim tenho essa linha por exemplo linha[1,2,3,4,5] e linha2[5,6,7,8,9] e ponto de corte por exemplo corte=2, ele resulta em 2 linhas novas linha[1,2,7,8,9] e linha2[5,6,3,4,5] @PedrovonHertwig

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver meu problema, na verdade era muito simples, eu estava utilizando o **setitem** no list, então como o código para modificar estavam juntos e quando se alterava o primeiro o segundo iria utiliza-lo ja modificado e isso causava o erro na saida. Como solução criei duas variavel `filho1` e `filho2` que recebem o item alterado e depois foi alterado na lista.

### SOLUÇÃO:

```
def crossover(probCrossover):
     indices = []
     randoms = []

     print('\nCROSSOVER')
     print('-----'*6)
     for i in range(len(populacao)):
        randoms.append(random())

     for i , r in enumerate(randoms):
         if r <= probCrossover:
             indices.append(i)

     if len(indices)%2!=0:
         indices.pop()
     print('\nINDICES: {}'.format(indices))
     for ind in range(0, len(indices), 2):

         pontoCorte = randint(1, precind)
         print('Corte em: {}'.format(pontoCorte))
         print('Pai: {}\nMae: {}'.format(populacao[indices[ind]], populacao[indices[ind+1]]))
         filho1 = populacao[indices[ind]][0:pontoCorte]+populacao[indices[ind+1]][pontoCorte:]
         filho2 = populacao[indices[ind+1]][0:pontoCorte]+populacao[indices[ind]][pontoCorte:]

         populacao.__setitem__(indices[ind], filho1)
         populacao.__setitem__(indices[ind+1], filho2)
```